# Count the whole column that matches your multiple criteria

Tags: countif

```
               1    2   3
```

Attribute 1
Attribute 2
Attribute 3

```
           
1. Attribute 1  Attribute 2 Attribute 3 Grade
2.   Yes         Yes           No           1
3.   No          No            Yes          2
4.   Yes         No            No           1
5.   No          Yes           Yes          3
6.   No          No            Yes          2
```

I want cell B2 to return the number of counted YES in Attribute1 under Grade 1. Is there a COUNTIF formula referencing to multiple columns with condition?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is Excel, and the sparse matrix is the desired output format with `1` in B1, if so please try in B2 copied across and down to suit:

```
 =COUNTIFS(INDIRECT($A2);"Yes";Grade;B$1)
```

Since the location of the data is not mentioned I have used named ranges for convenience and since spaces are not allowed in range names have used underlines instead, so for example, have changed `Attribute 1` at the very top to `Attribute_1`.